# ChartJS radar chart start from 0 Angular cli

Tags: angular, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm using chartJS in Angular.
My problem is that when all data is set to 0, the chart reach the 2nd tick instead of being just a dot in the center:
[image: chart with all 0]

When I have other data and only some are 0 then it shows correct

adding the relevant code:

```
data: {
                labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: '',
                        data:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,105,0, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'green',
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#green',
                        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                        pointHoverBorderColor: 'green',
                    },
                ],
            },
                options: {
scales: {
                        r: {
                            ticks: {
                                display: false,
                            },
                            pointLabels: {
                                padding: 13,
                            },
                            suggestedMin: 0,
                            suggestedMax: 0,
                        },
                    },
    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        datalabels: {
                            align: 'end',
                            display: true,
                            offset: 1,
                        },
                    },
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: `suggestedMin: 0, suggestedMax: 0` is useless, since it can't have both min and max zero, and doesn't solve the ambiguity (note that even if it's not common and it's counterintuitive and possibly absurd for many cases, you *can* represent.negative `r` data on a `chart.js` radar). If you want the minimum to be zero, you'll have to set `suggestedMax` as a positive value, smaller than the scale of the possible non-zero data.